# How to make link into img tag work with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drupal

I have two scripts, one turns links into youtube player it works with ajax and now I wanted to do same but with img links to make it into img tag and this one doesnt work with ajax, by ajax I mean it's in the forum thread and pager is ajax if you go to the next page it doesn't work anymore you have to refresh window.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var r = /^((?:https?:)?\/\/)?((?:www|m)\.)?((?:youtube\.com|youtu.be))(\/(?:[\w\-]+\?v=|embed\/|v\/)?)((?!\bchannel\b)[\w\-]+)([\S]+)?$/;
    function c() {
        $("#content-content a").each(function () {
            var e,
                o,
                t = $(this).attr("href"),
                c = r.exec(t);
            null !== c &&
                (console.log(c[5], c[6]),
                (e = c[5]),
                void 0 !== c[6] && c[6].toLowerCase().includes("t=") && (e += c[6]),
                console.log(e),
                (o = '<iframe width="100%" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{youtubeVideoId}" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>'.replace(
                    "{youtubeVideoId}",
                    e
                )),
                $(this).replaceWith(o));
        });
    }
    c(),
        (Drupal.behaviors.YtUrlToPlayerBehaviour = function (e, o) {
            $(document).ajaxComplete(function (e, o, t) {
                c();
            });
        });
});
</script>

<script>
$('a[href$=".png"], a[href$=".jpg"], a[href$=".gif"], a[href$=".tiff"], a[href$=".webp"]').each(function(){
    $(this).html('<img src="' + $(this).attr('href') + '" />');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script (the stuff at the bottom to do with images) if only evaluated and called when the page loads.

Drupal has a javascript object called 'Drupal.behaviors' which is basically a list of functions it will call when the page has finishes loading ie. '$(document).ready()' or when an ajax call has completed.

What you want to do is attach your own function to this list of behaviors so your code is executed when the page load or when some ajax has completed. You can see the other youtube code doing it with 'Drupal.behaviors.YtUrlToPlayerBehaviour'.

If you want more details, read [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview) or [here](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/understanding-javascript-behaviors-in-drupal)

This code will probably work for you.

```
Drupal.behaviors.myImageBehavior = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    $('a[href$=".png"], a[href$=".jpg"], a[href$=".gif"], a[href$=".tiff"], a[href$=".webp"]', context).each(function(){
      $(this).html('<img src="' + $(this).attr('href') + '" />');
    });
  }
}
```

Take note of the 'context' variable, on page load this would be the document, but after an ajax call, it will be what was returned by the ajax. Using the context variable make sure that you code is run only on what is new to the page at that time.

As with most things Drupal and Javascript, there are other approaches, but the code above is the standard way you would do it in Drupal.